# how to make bind submit working always? it's working from time to time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to compare to values (min - max) from two inputs
if min is greater than max should alert a message... that works

The problem is when I correct max value and submit again, it is showing the same alert...

this is my HTML:

```
<form>
  <input type="text" placeholder="min" id="input1" class="numberInput"/>
  <input type="text" placeholder="max" id="input2" class="numberInput"/>
  <input type="submit"/>
  <span class="msg"></span>
</form>
```

and this is my (relevant?) JS:

```
var $input1 = $("#input1");
var $input2 = $("#input2");

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('form').bind("submit", function(e) {
    if ($input1.val() > $input2.val()) {
        alert('min value is greater than max value');
        $input1.focus();
        e.preventDefault();
    } else {
        alert('normally submitted');
        evt.preventDefault();
    }
  })
})
```

You can find the full sample on http://jsfiddle.net/cruzj/Lcwhqjj7/1/

Thanks!!

Comment: Works fine in your fiddle....

Comment: Try using the submit method:

http://api.jquery.com/submit/

Comment: what happens if you move the jquery selector inside of the `bind` callback?

Comment: `evt.preventDefault();` in the `else` is suspicious, as you don't have an `evt` argument or variable anywhere.

Comment: Hmm, works fine , wat is the problem?

Comment: $('body').on("submit", "form", function(e) {}  try this, or i wrong understand ur problem?

Comment: The $ symbol in names of variables is really confusing, try to avoid it. Also consider using .on() function like Legendary suggested. For this kind of behavior is much better blur event - it will check the input in moment user leaves it.

Comment: I just checked again, on the else should said e.preventDefault() instead of evt....

Comment: Thank you Richard.... submit() jquery method seems working fine...

Answer (score 1):

.val() returns a string, so

```
$input1.val() > $input2.val() === true when input1 = "7" and input2 = "456456"
```

to avoid that comportement you have to use parseInt() function

```
parseInt($input1.val()) > parseInt($input2.val()) === false when input1 = "7" and input2 = "456456"
```

[example here](http://jsfiddle.net/jxds05fL/1/)

Comment: Or you can use Number() function.